# Asp .Net Core Identity automatically logout after some minutes

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

In one of my project, I used Microsoft identity for authorization and authentication. The problem is user automatically log out after some minutes of inactivity. This is my current setting:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/503";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.LoginPath = "/Index";
    
    
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

The application works fine in the development environment or in local IIS. However, this problem exist when I publish my application to the host provider. I wonder if there is anyway to solve this problem or if I missing some configurations.

Comment: I checked the application section in chrome debuger, cookies have valid expire time, however they don't work and user have to login again

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but in our project we use a tag in Web.config to set expiration time of a session:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="4800"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not solve my problem

Comment: it happens very fast, like 2 or 3 minutes